# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] while using angular with require

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I want to use require with angular and i created a sample application for learning.My code files look like this

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>RequireJs Demo</title>

    <script src="require.js" data-main="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myController">
{{message}}
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```js
require.config({
    paths: {
        angular: 'angular.min',
        angularresourse:'angular-resource.min'
    },
    
    shim: {
        angularresourse:['angular'],
        "angular": {
            exports: "angular"
        }
    }
});
require(['angular', 'module'],
    function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    }
);
```

module.js

```js
define(['angular', 'controller'], function (angular,controller) {
    angular.module('app',[])
        .controller('myController', controller);
});
```

controller.js

```js
define([], function () {
    var myController = function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "RequireJs Integrated successfully";
    };

    myController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    return myController;
});
```

But while executing this shows error as

> "angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…ttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8383%2FAngular_Require%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A390)"

Could someone help me please...

Answer (score 0):

In HTML use `ng-app="app"` like this

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
   <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>RequireJs Demo</title>

        <script src="require.js" data-main="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myController">
    {{message}}
    </body>
</html>
```

add JS file in your code.

Comment: add dependent js file in your html page.

Comment: I dont want include all my js files in index,html.To avoid that i am following require.js..This code is working and found in some tutorial in "codeproject",but not working when i copied the same

Comment: share the tutorial link here.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1069294/Integrating-requirejs-in-your-angularjs-applicatio

Comment: ok I read it. This error is related to the module or dependency js file.